Existence solutions of the system of equations on Riemannian manifold
Is there a way to show that the following system of two equations has a solution? I don't want to find an explicit solution, but just verify its existence.
$$f''(r) + \beta \coth(r) f'(r) = \rho_0 e^{-\alpha r},$$
$$f''(r) + (n-1) \coth(r) f'(r) = C f(r),$$
where $ \rho_0 > 0 $, $\alpha > 0 $,$\beta > 0 $ and $C$ are constants.
The function $f(r)$ is a radial function (where $r$ is supposed to be the distance to a fixed point in $M$)
and $f(r):M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$, where $M$ is an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold, complete and simply connected, with negative constant sectional curvature.

What does "radial" mean? Is your $r$ supposed to be the distance to a fixed point in $M$? Is your manifold $M$ supposed to be complete and simply connected?

Yes, you are right, sorry! I fixed my question.

This seems to have little to do with Riemannian manifolds. It seems to ask simply whether the same function satisfies two different ODEs. In general, the odds are overwhelmingly against it.
